# How to add str with str if it has delimiters such a dot or dash somewhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add str with str if it has delimiters such a dot or dash in the middle of the string. Slicing not help with this one

**example:**

```
a = 'Beautiful. is better5- than ugly'
b = 'UK- Paris- Check Tech2013'
```

**expected:**

```
a = 'Beautiful.is better5-than ugly'
b = 'UK-Paris-Check Tech2013'
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the input, and what you actually did to add the strings?

Comment: @Nick Did any answers help you with your original post, or might you clarify what you are attempting? So we might be able to help answer your question correctly. Also, what you have attempted in terms of code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
 
pat = r'([.-])\s+|'
re.sub(pat, '\\1', a)
 #'Beautiful.is better5-than ugly'

re.sub(pat, '\\1', b)
 #'UK-Paris-Check Tech2013'
```

The pattern `([.-])\s*` looks for either a `.` or a `-` then captures that as the first group. It then follows that with at least 1 horizontal space. All these are then replaced with the first captured group using `\\1`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont understand the regular expression, you can try this code.

code:

```
a = 'Beautiful. is better5- than ugly'
b = 'UK- Paris- Check Tech2013'
c = 'Beautiful  . is better5  - than ugly'

def replace_delimiters(s):
    delimiters = [". ","- "," ."," -"]
    while any([delimiter in s for delimiter in delimiters]):
        s = s.replace(". ",".").replace("- ","-").replace(" .",".").replace(" -","-")
    return s

print(replace_delimiters(a))
print(replace_delimiters(b))
print(replace_delimiters(c))
```

result:

```
Beautiful.is better5-than ugly
UK-Paris-Check Tech2013
Beautiful.is better5-than ugly
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` is useful when used in the right order.

```
def format(s: str) -> str:
    return s.replace('. ', '.').replace('- ', '-')

print(format('Beautiful. is better5- than ugly'))
print(format('UK- Paris- Check Tech2013'))
# Output
# a = 'Beautiful.is better5-than ugly'
# b = 'UK-Paris-Check Tech2013'
```

Comment: Why the join? You already start with a string, joining it with the empty string will only return the original one.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you. It is most simplest solution. This code will work only in case if you have  one space after `'.'` or `'-'`

```
    s = input("")
    s1=s.replace(". ",'.')
    s2=s1.replace("- ",'-')
    print(s2)
```